# Using seekg() when taking input from redirected stdin

Tags: c++, seekg

So i'm trying to read in a string of characters twice using cin.get(). The input is being redirected as "program < input". So it is valid to use seekg().

As the titel says, I thought I would be able to use seekg() to save the beginning position of the string, so I could come back to use the starting position of the same string again.

Here is my attempt:

```
char c;
while (cin.get(c))
{
  //do stuff 
}

cin.seekg(0, ios::beg);

while (cin.get(c))
{
  //do stuff with the string a second time
}
```

The second while loop isn't doing anything, so I'm obviously not using seekg correctly. Could someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

You can't seek on streams/pipes. They don't continue to exist in memory. Imagine the keyboard is directly connected to your program. The only operation you can do with a keyboard is ask for more input. It has no history.

If it's just a keyboard you can't seek, but if it's redirected with < in the shell seeking works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cin.seekg(1, std::ios::beg);
  if (std::cin.fail()) 
    std::cout << "Failed to seek\n";
  std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  if (std::cin.fail()) 
    std::cout << "Failed to seek\n";

  if (!std::cin.fail()) 
    std::cout << "OK\n";
}
```

Gave:

> user@host:/tmp > ./a.out
>   Failed to seek
>   Failed to seek
>   user@host:/tmp > ./a.out < test.cc
>   OK

Comment: hmmm this is weird, because my homework specifications require us take input from stdin. My professor said that in order to make two passes over the input, we need to use seekg()... Maybe i'm misunderstanding the guidelines. 

Would it work if I used input redicrection? Such as "program < input"

Comment: @WakkaWakkaWakka - I think that should work provided your shell sets up the redirection sensibly.

Comment: Then would i not use cin.seekg(0, ios::beg) to return to the beginning of the redirected input?

Comment: @WakkaWakkaWakka - you can seek if it's connected to a file. I added an example that shows that.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was getting so frustrated with this syntax

Comment: But Now i'm back to my original problem, can we not use seekg() to read in the string of characters twice?

Comment: @WakkaWakkaWakka - I think you have a different problem. Check `cin.fail()` after everything - I'd bet it's failing somewhere and not being reset.

Comment: I'm betting this behaviour is shell-specific. Could you clarify your answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're probably right that betting on it without more specific circumstances might not be wise although I'm struggling to dig out a reference anywhere. That said it's be a pretty awful shell that went out of its way on Linux to not just do `open()`, `dup2()` and picked some more complex, less efficient scheme for redirects.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. std::cin is usually connected to a terminal, and so random access is out of the question.

You could do that if the stream you were using was a std::istringstream or an std::ifstream.

My advice is to read all the characters from std::cin into a single std::string, then create a std::istringstream from that string, and then try your techniques on that std::istringstream instead of std::cin.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot seek on streams. You must unget the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't seek on streams, but you can use either `std::cin.peek()` or `std::cin.unget()`.

1) By using `cin.peek()`

```
char c;
while (c = cin.peek())
{
  //do stuff 
}

while (cin.get(c))
{
  //do stuff with the string a second time
}
```

2) By using `cin.unget()`

```
char c;
while (cin.get(c))
{
  //do stuff 
}

cin.unget();

while (cin.get(c))
{
  //do stuff with the string a second time
}
```