# cat filename | command and command < filename behaving differently

Tags: c++, inputstream, stdin

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    int main() {
        std::string str;
        char magic[9];
        std::cin.read((char *)magic, sizeof(magic));

        std::cout << "eof/fail=" << std::cin.eof() << '/' << std::cin.fail() << '\n';
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        std::cout << "eof/fail=" << std::cin.eof() << '/' << std::cin.fail() << '\n';

        while (std::cin >> str) {
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

my code contains implementation of seekg(0) fucntion on std::cin

it is behaving differently
when run as
    `./a.out < filename`
and 
    `cat filename | ./a.out`

I was considering both the ways equivalent .
but I am surprised to see that they behave differently

my question is What is the main difference in both ways ? 
Aren't they both a way to get standard input ?

Comment: You can not seek in a pipe, it's one-direction only.

Comment: in what way do they behave differently? What is the question?

Comment: Yes, they behave differently.  Was there a question?

Comment: my question is what is the basic difference between both the approaches

Comment: If you want any broader explanation than what I've posted below, you're first going to have to show evidence that you've researched a basic understanding of how terminals, shells and pipes work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wasn't able to figure out the main cause of problem. is it terminal/shell or is it input stream of C++.

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't they both a way to get standard input ?

Yes, but…

> I was considering both the ways equivalent .

They are very much not equivalent.

```
cat filename | ./a.out
```

Here, your shell runs the program `cat`, telling it to echo the contents of a file called `filename`. It also runs the program `a.out`. It opens up a "pipe" between them and streams information from one's standard output stream, to the other's standard input stream.

```
./a.out < filename
```

Here, your shell runs the program `a.out`, making the file `filename` available via the process's standard input stream. This is called *input redirection*.

---

You can seek around a "file" (more generally, block device). In the case of input redirection from a file, your shell cleverly tells your program that it can treat the stream as a block device, so you can enjoy seekness.

But, with a pipe, [once you've consumed your data, that's it it's gone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765759/560648). You can't go back to the beginning; it's not a container. It's a flow of data.